# How to make a PDF file read - only using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to create a PDF so that the user can only read it but not edit it. How i can do this with PHP or some lib for PHP. Now i using PDFtk, but I can't do to change the editing I was shown Russian letters in PDF form.

Answer (score 0):

for you to be able to create a pdf file u need to download fpdf in the particular folder you are working with

check this link out, it will help you on how to go about it

https://youtu.be/0KiqCSy0jHA

if it helps let me know